# CAShapeLayer freaks out when UIView Animation Occurs

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, core-graphics

I have a `CAShapeLayer` that consists of multiple sublayers which comprise a graphic that is made up of a lot of paths. I stored this graphic in CAShapeLayer for performance purposes not with the intention of actually animating it (just need to change the color and resize it). What I'm noticing is, everytime I do a `UIView` animation (ie the view transitions or I do one manually), the `CAShapeLayer` seems to reload itself or do something that is making the other animation choppy. It also occurs if I use my finger to move the `UIView` which houses this `CAShapeLayer`. Why is this happening and how do I prevent this from happening?

UPDATE: After profiling appears a lot of the work is being done in

```
-[CALayer drawInContext:]
```

Comment: Try setting the shouldRasterize property on your shape layer to YES during animation

Comment: Thanks. This helped a little bit, but there was still stuttering.

Comment: You can also try rendering the layer to an image and then displaying that, each time you make a change (e.g. color) you can rerender the new state and then animate your image's change to the new image.